# Save Configuration Settings to XML file in QT?

Tags: qt, configuration, settings, configuration-files

I want to Save Configuration Settings to XML file in QT and read it from there ?

What is best approach to do this in QT ?

Any sample/ideas are highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't necessarily need XML, you can go for QSettings. Otherwise you'll need to parse and write the XML using QXmlStreamReader/Writer or QDomDocument.

Comment: @Frank : Can u suggest me some simple example to understand QSettings ?

Comment: The QSettings documentation should contain enough examples?

Answer (score 7):

You can register your XML file format with [`QSettings::registerFormat`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#registerFormat)

Here's a sample implementation of the [`readXmlFile` and `writeXmlFile`](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/8743-QSettings-my-own-format-of-config-file?s=af167a56fbf66edc5f566f5106bf75cb&p=54105#post54105)

Comment: But Qsettings will save in memory i guess. i want to save 2 some file & read it from there...

Comment: The sample implementation uses `QXmlStreamWriter` to save configuration file in an instance of `QIODevice`, which would be usually a `QFile`

Comment: The sample implementations don't work at all with QSettings internal representation of key value pairs. For e.g. If you write an array to QSettings using beginWriteArray/endArray, the writer function writes a pretty badly formatted XML with tag name for array elements starting with numbers ( <1>Value</1>). This is illegal. There is no working read/write XML implementations I have come across as of yet which takes into consideration "arrays".

Answer (score 2):

[There](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/examples-xml.html) is Qt examples for XML.

Also you can use [QSettings](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsettings.html) to store your settings.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code for exporting settings to XML. What you need is to call `ExportSettingsToXml()` with opened for writing QFile. The exported file can be imported again with `ImportSettingsFromXml()`.

```
QString Variant2Text( const QVariant &value )
{
    switch (value.type())
    {
    case QVariant::String:
    case QVariant::Int:
    case QVariant::UInt:
    case QVariant::LongLong:
    case QVariant::ULongLong:
    case QVariant::Double:
    case QVariant::Bool:
        return value.toString();
    }

    QByteArray ba;
    value.save(QDataStream(&ba, QIODevice::WriteOnly));

    return QString(ba.toHex());
}

QVariant Text2Variant( const QString &sText, QVariant::Type nType )
{
    switch (nType)
    {
    case QVariant::String:
    case QVariant::Int:
    case QVariant::UInt:
    case QVariant::LongLong:
    case QVariant::ULongLong:
    case QVariant::Double:
    case QVariant::Bool:
        {
            QVariant var(sText);
            if (var.convert(nType))
                return var;

            return QVariant(sText);
        }
        return QVariant::fromValue(sText);
    }

    QVariant value;
    value.load(QDataStream(&QByteArray::fromHex(sText.toLatin1()), QIODevice::ReadOnly));

    return value;
}

void XmlExportSettingsRecursive(QXmlStreamWriter &writer, QSettings &settings, const QStringList &blackList)
{
    QString sGroup = settings.group();

    if (!sGroup.isEmpty())
    {
        writer.writeStartElement("group");  
        writer.writeAttribute(QStringLiteral("name"), sGroup.mid(sGroup.indexOf(QChar('/')) + 1));
    }
    // Write child groups first
    {
        const QStringList &listGroups = settings.childGroups();
        foreach (const QString &group, listGroups)
        {
            settings.beginGroup(group);         
            XmlExportSettingsRecursive(writer, settings, blackList);
            settings.endGroup();
        }
    }

    const QStringList &listKeys = settings.childKeys();
    foreach (const QString &key, listKeys)
    {
        if (blackList.contains(key))
            continue;

        writer.writeStartElement("key");
        writer.writeAttribute(QStringLiteral("name"), key);
        const QVariant &value = settings.value(key);
        writer.writeAttribute(QStringLiteral("type"), value.typeName());
        writer.writeCharacters(Variant2Text(value));
        writer.writeEndElement();
    }

    if (!sGroup.isEmpty())
        writer.writeEndElement();
}

bool XmlImportSettingsRecursive(QXmlStreamReader &reader, QSettings &settings)
{
    while (!reader.atEnd()) {
        reader.readNext();
        if (reader.isStartElement())
        {           
            if (reader.name() == QStringLiteral("group"))
            {
                const QXmlStreamAttributes &attr = reader.attributes();
                QString sGroup = attr.value(QStringLiteral("name")).toString();

                settings.beginGroup(sGroup);
                if (!XmlImportSettingsRecursive(reader, settings))
                    return false;
                settings.endGroup();
            }
            else if (reader.name() == QStringLiteral("key"))
            {
                const QXmlStreamAttributes &attr = reader.attributes();
                const QString &sKey = attr.value(QStringLiteral("name")).toString();
                const QString &sType = attr.value(QStringLiteral("type")).toString();
                if (reader.readNext())
                {
                    if (reader.isCharacters() || reader.isEndElement())
                    {
                        const QString &sValue = reader.text().toString();
                        settings.setValue(sKey, Text2Variant(sValue, QVariant::nameToType(sType.toLatin1())));
                    }
                    else
                        continue;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (reader.isEndElement() && reader.name() == QStringLiteral("group"))
            return true;
    }
    if (reader.hasError()) {
        qDebug()<<reader.errorString();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

bool ExportSettingsToXml( QIODevice *device, const QString &settingsGroup = QString(), const QStringList &blackList = QStringList())
{   
    if (!device || !device->isWritable())
        return false;

    QSettings settings;
    settings.beginGroup(settingsGroup);

    QXmlStreamWriter xmlWriter( device );
    xmlWriter.setAutoFormatting( true );
    xmlWriter.writeStartDocument();

    xmlWriter.writeStartElement( QStringLiteral("settings") );

    if (!settingsGroup.isEmpty())
    {   
        xmlWriter.writeStartElement(QStringLiteral("group"));
        xmlWriter.writeAttribute(QStringLiteral("name"), settingsGroup);
    }

    XmlExportSettingsRecursive(xmlWriter, settings, blackList);

    if (!settingsGroup.isEmpty())
        xmlWriter.writeEndElement();

    xmlWriter.writeEndDocument();

    return true;
}

bool ImportSettingsFromXml( QIODevice *device, const QString &settingsGroup = QString())
{
    if (!device || !device->isReadable())
    {
        qDebug()<<"Trying to import XML settings from non-readable device";
        return false;
    }

    QSettings settings;
    settings.beginGroup(settingsGroup);
    QXmlStreamReader xmlReader( device );
    xmlReader.readNext();
    if (!xmlReader.isStartDocument())
    {
        qDebug()<<"Invalid xml document format";
        return false;
    }

    if (!xmlReader.readNextStartElement())
    {
        qDebug()<<"Empty settings xml document";
        return true;
    }

    if (xmlReader.name() == QStringLiteral("settings") )
    {
        if (!XmlImportSettingsRecursive(xmlReader, settings))
            return false;
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"Unknown settings format.";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For such things I often use the [boost library](http://www.boost.org/) for C+ and can highly recommend it. It offers serialization for various formats like XML, text, binary etc.

[Serialization Tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html) (looks more complicated that it actually is)

Comment: Qt works at its best when it works with itself. Boost is good but integrating it will be messy unless it's encapsulated in a Qt format. Why introduce another library dependency?

Comment: True, it's another dependency. It's just my personal experience with boost. Easy to use and fast and boost includes haven't made my projects _messy_ yet.