# Is it possible to Serialize QSettings and then recover them?

Tags: c++, qt, qsettings

I would like to pass the settings saved with QSetting through two instances of an application, for example through a socket.

I could not see any function in the official documentation. The only thing I read is for example this post

[Save Configuration Settings to XML file in QT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593749/save-configuration-settings-to-xml-file-in-qt)

But I do not want to save the settings in a XML file, for example in Windows I want to continue using the Registry.

I just want to collect all the settings, and pass them through a socket. And the receiver could check the settings and eventually substitute its own settings with the received ones.

Well, I suppose I could do something similar using QSettings::allKeys(), checking all the values, convert to strings, etc etc...but do you know if there is some native function in Qt already implemented?

Thanks to everyone in advance

Comment: You may try `boost::property_tree` for that. `QSettings` is not designed for such stuff. But you may use your own reader/writer with `QSettings` (register QSettings custom format).

Comment: I guess you can just implement your own [WriteFunc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#WriteFunc-typedef) and [ReadFunc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#ReadFunc-typedef) for sockets, shouln'd be to hard to serialize a `QMap` over the network, there might be some helper functions you can even use.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I do not want to register another format. I want to use the native format for each platform. I just want to pass the settings from one application to another. For example in Windows, I want to read all the settings in the Registry and serialize them in order to send them into a socket. It should be much simpler....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best solution that I found:

Create a QMap from QSettings

```
QMap<QString, QVariant> keysValuesPairs;
QStringList keys = settings.allKeys();
QStringListIterator it(keys);
while ( it.hasNext() )
{
    QString currentKey = it.next();
    keysValuesPairs.insert(currentKey, settings.value(currentKey));
}
```

And then write it in a QJson with the function (see the official documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html)

QJsonObject::fromVariantMap

then in the other side recover it with

QJsonObject::toVariantMap()

and rewrite the settings

```
for ( int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++ )
{
    settings.setValue( keys.at(i), keysValuesPairsMap.value(keys.at(i)) );
}
```